# How to make a cell overlap?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make cells overlapping.

[image]

What I did is 
Adjust the tableview's contentSize:

```
int count = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width ,(100 * count - 30 * (count - 1)));
```

And set the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    if (indexPath.row != 0) {
      UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0]];
      [currentCell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, - 30, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But when I test, this is not working.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it will work by try with:
1) Configure a view inside viewForHeaderInSection with height 50 
2) setting the row height to 70 in heightForRowAtIndexPath method
3) for each row setClipsToBounds:FALSE
4) Keep the contentSize as you have

Comment: Please add an explanation what do you want to achieve on app level with this i.e. what is the purpose of this overlap. It will help us to reason better about the problem.

Comment: I want to implement a animation likes [this link](http://162.243.98.252/videos/MakingSwipe/MakingSwipe.hyperesources/NikeSwipe.mov)

Comment: I have to disappoint you but the road to such an animation is very different from what you are suggesting i.e. cell overlapping. That code in the animation was either done via AsyncDisplaykit framework, or using UIDynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happing with your code is that the values that you are manually setting inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are getting overwritten by the UITableViewController layout methods.

You are not supposed to edit the frame of a table view cell directly since this is an attribute that is set by UITableViewController internally. You should only interact with this by using methods of the UITableViewDelegate protocol. (`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, ...)

IMHO the best way (cleanest one) to implement what you are describing is to subclass UICollectionView instead of UITableView and define a custom layout.

However if you wanna go the hacky way you can achieve an apparent row overlapping in many different ways.

Just as an example, you could create two different row types, one with height 30 and one with height 70, where the first one represents the overlapping part of the row and the second one represents the not-overlapping part of the row. Then use the first type for even rows and the second one for odd rows.

Hope this helps.

p.s. i'm really sorry if my english is not the best

Comment: I am new to UICollectionView layout. Can you help me with some code?

Comment: The absolute best resources are these two: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html) is some great sample code but if you want a better and more complete introduction you can watch the official presentation where Apple engineers explained UICollectionView, [Introducing Collection View](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/). Otherwise you can find countless tutorials online that explain everything 100x better than i would here.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputations to upvote your answer. Thanks.